# Regular Expression to find uncommented line (Or match lines NOT containing ')

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to parse some code using RegEx's, and I need to match any lines containing code which has NOT been commented out.

For example:

```
Public Function SomeFunc(SomeVar As Integer) As Boolean
               Dim APSHSwitch, objDB, sql, iCnt, vADOConn, result As New Object
    '''        Dim BPSHSwitch, objDB, sql, iCnt, vADOConn, result As New Object
               'Dim CPSHSwitch, objDB, sql, iCnt, vADOConn, result As New Object\
End Function
```

I need to match:

```
Dim APSHSwitch, objDB, sql, iCnt, vADOConn, result As New Object
```

So far I have the following, which matches all three.

```
Dim\s
(?<varNames>([A-Z0-9]+(,\s){1})+[A-Z0-9]+)
\sAs\s
(?<newKeyWord>(New\s)?)
(?<varType>([A-Z]+))
```

I need to match only the 1st line with no comments. I can't figure it out.

Comment: It may be overkill for your purposes, but anyway, have you considered MS Roslyn ?

Comment: I hadn't heard of Roslyn before. I just read up on that. It's overkill for our immediate purposes, but we have some major refactorings to do in the future. This may help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this matching using the following RegEx with multiline ON

```
(?<!^\s*\'+\s*)
Dim\s
(?<varNames>([A-Z0-9]+(,\s){1})+[A-Z0-9]+)
\sAs\s
(?<newKeyWord>(New\s)?)
(?<varType>([A-Z]+))
```

Thanks to LastCoder!

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're using /* */ or any nested commenting, i wouldn't even try regex.

But if you're just looking for lines that start with `"'''"`, then I'd go match commented lines instead of the ones that are not commented, and then adjust your conditionals accordingly.

fore example

```
"^\s*'''\s*.*$
```

will match commented lines

Comment: I need to ignore the commented lines. I'm writing a code scrubber. We have a very large and very ugly code base here. So this is a small piece of the logic to identify variables in our code so we can automate a few improvements, such as earlybinding.

Comment: @BrettEmerson so then ignore lines that match the regex.

Comment: That was an option, but the code is presently structured to deal with matches making this less ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative look-behind to the beginning of your regex

```
(?<!^\s*\')

Explanation: The line doesN'T (?<!) start with (^) any amount of white space (\s*) and an apostrophe (\').
```

Comment: That dosen't seem to work. All 3 lines are matched. I'll try to play with this approach to see if I can fix it and report back if I do.

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding this: (?<!^\s*\'+\s*)   I also needed to turn multiline on. I'll post this as an answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Brett Emerson - thinking about it further, in your specific case just adding a ^\s* to the beginning of your original RegEx would probably be a enough. That way your forcing it to match ONLY white space from the beginning of the line to the Dim.